# How to run jq command in python?

Tags: python, jq

I am following a bigquery geospatial guide, and my json file is changed via a jq command. Specifically this one:

`cat ~/file1.json | jq -c '.features[]' > converted.json`

I'm having difficulties running the equivalent of above in python. I'm using the subprocess module, and it's not working.

`cmd = ['cat', './sample.json', '|', 'c', '.features[]']`

`print(subprocess.check_output(cmd))`

the output im getting is this:

```
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: -c: No such file or directory
cat: .features[]: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rtom/kml2geo/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    result = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/Users/rtom/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/Users/rtom/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cat', './sample.json', '|', '-c', '.features[]']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
(base) rtom@Ryans-MacBook-Pro kml2geo %
```

Any help here?

Comment: There's no reason to use `cat` here _at all_, and it's far easier if you don't.

Comment: (and why `subprocess.check_output()` when you want your output to go _direct to a file_?)

Comment: BTW, the shell equivalent to a `stdin=open('filename', 'r')` argument to `subprocess.Popen`-family functions in Python is to use `<filename`; that can go on either the beginning or end, so `<filename jq ...` or `jq ... <filename` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `cat` (you don't *ever* need `cat` when reading from a single file; its purpose is to *concatenate* multiple input sources together). Take it out, and everything gets far easier:

```py
subprocess.run(['jq', '-c', '.features[]'],
               stdin=open(os.path.expanduser('~/file1.json'), 'r'),
               stdout=open('converted.json', 'w'))
```

You can also avoid the `stdin=` argument by passing the input filename (after replacing the `~` with a fully-qualified path, since there's no shell to do it for you) on jq's command line:

```py
subprocess.run(['jq', '-c', '.features[]',
                os.path.expanduser('~/file1.json')
               ], stdout=open('converted.json', 'w'))
```

If you want to read output to a variable instead of writing it to a file, take out the `stdout=` argument and add `capture_output=True`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. Happy new year friend.